# How should I find the index of several possible characters?

Tags: linux, perl

I realize the question name doesn't really tell much but I didn't really know how to explain it shortly, so here's the long version.

First, here's my current code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input;
while (<>) {
        $input .= $_;
}
$input =~ s/ |\n//g;

print "\n";
```

What I want to do is make a calculator, e.g. when a user does `echo "8 * 5 +   21-15" | calculate` it will calculate it correctly. So here's my thought progress. First I take the string as a whole and strip it of all whitespace characters. Then I wanted to index() it for the occurence of *, +, / or -. Then I wanted to add all the characters before any of those operators to a string and then (int) the string and then do the same to the part after the operator and then do the operation between them. But I don't actually have much of a clue on how to do this. Also, I'm very new to Perl (3 days experience) so please go slowly on me if possible.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `echo "8 * 5 + 21-15" | perl -ne 'print eval()'`

Comment: Read up on recursive descent parsers; you should really parse the line as a whole before trying to perform any operations. Imagine '3 + 5*8'; you would find the "+" first, but that needs to wait until you do the multiplication.

Comment: This is a rather complex task for a perl beginner, and I assume its for learning purposes. Otherwise, you should take Fredrik's advice above and simply use perl's already working math functionality.

Comment: Well, I asked a friend of mine whether he could give me a lesson or something to test what I learned. This is what he gave me.

Comment: Perhaps start with something easier... I'd recommend start solving the problems at http://projecteuler.net/ using perl before moving into the dark corners of the language.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for something like ProjectEuler forever! :D

Comment: It sounds like you want a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can accept that your calculator won't be able to handle parenthesis, use a regular expression to parse the string for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @tokens = <STDIN> =~ /(\d+|\+|-|\*|\/)/g;
print "$_\n" for @tokens;
```

this will provide you with an array of tokens that you can work on, so

```
echo "8 * 5 + 21-15" | script.pl
```

will print

```
8
*
5
+
21
-
15
```

Now it's up to you to write some code that does the right calculations on the tokens. It isn't too hard if you don't try parsing parens, but if you do, you'll need to write a recursive parser, which is much harder.

Comment: Take a look at the perlre manual for more information on regular expressions.